# Which two languages are the most unlike each other?

Tags: language-change, dead-languages

So, which two existing languages are the least like each other?

Comment: There are too many pairs like that. The question looks too broad.

Comment: Human and animal language!

Comment: We don't have data on every language so, even apart from there being no metric for 'difference' or 'similarity', we can't begin to try and answer a question like this.

Comment: But... a fun contrast is [whistled languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whistled_language) and [sign languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_language).

Comment: klingon/vulcan definitely

Answer (score 3):

There is no applicable metric, so the question has no answer. To measure similarity, you could try to enumerate the differences between two (very similar) languages, and keep a tab of the points of difference. For instance, Swedish and Norwegian are very similar, but where Swedish has many plural endings *-ar, -or, -er*, Norwegian only has -er. But if that one difference or two -- is the difference "Norwegian only has -er", or "Norwegian doesn't have -or" and "Norwegian doesn't have -ar"? Then, what would a comparison of Swedish and Finnish reveal? One approach to plurals in Finnish is that there is a non-nominative plural suffix -i- and a general plural -t-. Swedish doesn't have a special case-determined plural suffix, so that's one. Finnish -*t*- is not the same as Swedish -*or, -ar -er*, but it is not totally unlike -- both have a lingual (coronal) consonant. So you would have to award fractional points for partial similarity.

Except, the Finnish plural -t- is actually not realized as [t] most of the time -- you have to do a fair amount of phonological analysis to get to this conclusion about the plural. So should similarity be based on abstract underlying forms, or on the specific phonetic form in given words? There is no scale for quantifying non-identity, so the question can't be answered.

Using "mutually unintelligibility" yields the simple conclusion that English is as dissimilar to Greek as it is to Chinese, in other words, most languages are completely "dissimilar".

Well, this just in... [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HHa7C4Dbjsw#t=59) has a striking similarity to Norwegian, but is completely not intelligible with Norwegian.